# Libreoffice forgets which are the open toolbars each time it starts

Tags: libreoffice

When I open a docx file created by MS Office, Libreoffice comes up with about ten toolbars opened, most of which I don't want to be there and use up space from my screen.  So I close the useless ones, one by one.

This is on Linux. Shouldn't Libreoffice remember the toolbars that I want to be open on MS Office files that I receive?  Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: If on Windows: Perhaps it was installed by Administrator, and settings are only retained when run as such. Try running as Administrator, hiding unwanted toolbars, and closing to see if changes were retained.

Comment: Thanks. I tested more and clarified. I'm on Linux. And this happens with files created by MS Office

Comment: Perhaps save in ODT format, instead of Word's format? Likely, there is *no place in the MS Word files* to store the *LibreOffice proprietary toolbar info*. If you must send files to others as DOCX, just save the final copy in that format.

Comment: The problem is not when saving, it is when opening the file. I routinely receive files created with MS office and when I open them I see many more open toolbars than I'd like. How can I make LO remember which toolbars I want to be open on MS office files that were never opened before? I clarified my question